# Android Pie 9.0 take user to Notification Center

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, android-9.0-pie

I am taking user to Notification center to control their push notifications preferences and read it from my app, and set to a switch toggle. I have different action for Lollipop and Oreo, but currently application is crashing for Android Pie 9.0. How can I fix that issue?

```
public void onPushSwitchChanged(View v){
    if(v.isPressed()){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1){
            intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", mContext.getPackageName());
        }else if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
            intent.putExtra("app_package", mContext.getPackageName());
            intent.putExtra("app_uid", mContext.getApplicationInfo().uid);
        }else {
            intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + mContext.getPackageName()));
        }
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And the error is

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
```

Comment: Show stacktrace and part of the code where it is happening.

Comment: Can you also share the [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/2745495) and the [codes you used](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that resulted in the crash? We can't see your code, your IDE, and your phone so it's impossible for anyone here to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update,

I fixed the issue by adding,

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

in my first if block.